# Immersion and Embedding problem

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Prove that:

1. A $C^r$-immersion $f:M \rightarrow N$ is a local $C^r$-embedding.
2. A differential map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m, f \in C^r, r\geq 0, m\geq n$ is a immersion if $\operatorname{rank}df_p=n, \forall p\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Thanks for regarding!

Comment: What is the definition of immersion you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: 1) Use the inverse function theorem. 2) What does the proof of the inverse function theorem say about f?